# Is it common for contracts to be voided on the grounds that they are unreadable?

Tags: contract-law

Not illegible- as far as I know, no one's signed the Voynich manuscript and been held to it- but simply incoherent, needlessly verbose, or prohibitively lengthy?

I recognize that legal language uses a lot of terms of art, and that it's necessarily going to be a bit abstruse, but it seems like most terms of use are entries in some sick competition to see who can ensure as few people as possible actually read the thing.

Comment: In the title "Is it common for" might lend itself to answers that are opinions where "Can" would lead to answers that are more concrete.

Answer (score 1):

No, the length, verbosity, or number of terms of art don't affect the validity of a document as evidence of a contract.

However, in-artful drafting can lead to ambiguity. Complexity for its own sake can backfire.